# Analytic function with convergent sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{z_n\}$ be a convergent sequence and $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ be analytic with $f(z_n)=n$for all n.Then
a)$f\equiv0$.  
                                                                                     b)f is bounded.   
                                                                            c)no such function exist.  
                                                         d)f has no zero.

Comment: What are your toughts, I mean clearly a) and b) are not suitable choices agree ?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Take a close bounded set $K$ containing your sequence $(z_n)$, $K$ is compact. This is possible as the sequence converges. $f$ being holomorphic is continuous. Hence the image of $K$ is compact, in particular bounded. In contradiction with the hypothesis $f(z_n)=n$. Conclusion: no such function exists.

To say it in a simpler way. An holomorphic function is continuous. And the image of a convergent sesquence by a continuous function is convergent. Which leads to a contradiction with your hypothesis.

Comment: yes this is correct ans.Thank you.